# how to make vertical column headers on automatic column generation?

Tags: laravel, tabulator

how to make **vertical column headers** on **automatic column generation** in **tabulator** js library?

i did this, and it works just fine:

```
    //define data
    var tabledata = {!!$one!!}

    //define table
    var table = new Tabulator("#table-1", {
        data:tabledata,
        autoColumns:true,
        layout:"fitColumns",
    });
```

but, when i add "headerVertical:true" it doesn't make any change:

```
    //define data
    var tabledata = {!!$one!!}

    //define table
    var table = new Tabulator("#table-1", {
        data:tabledata,
        autoColumns:true,
        headerVertical:true,
        layout:"fitColumns",
    });
```

can anyone help me with making vertical column headers while columns are generating automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

headerVertical only works if you define columns as per [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/columns#vertical), how ever you can use simple css to achieve that 
https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/t0gw9jbp/5/

to rotate 180 degrees use [CSS rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate)

```
   .tabulator-col-title {
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  /* if you use rotate change this to paddig-bottom*/
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* incase of rotation*/
}
```

Comment: thank you!!! it worked like a charm. but, i'm wondering how to make it rotate 180 degree? so that column headers starts from bottom to top?